# Should I prefer Func<T, TResult> or Converter<TIn, TOut>?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm writing a class with a type parameter `T` that accepts a delegate that converts the instance of `T` to a string. I could declare the type of such delegate as `Func<T, string>` or `Converter<T, string>`. Any reason I should prefer one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Converter because that's what your class requires: a converter.

You can, of course, use Func, but that Func would do the job of a Converter, so your intention is much clearer if you use Converter

Answer (score 5):

The delegate definitions are identical in everything but name.  Hence the only real value this could provide is preventing unnecessary allocations trying to convert from the input delegate type to the type you choose.  In short if all of your input delegates are `Func` choosing `Converter` will cause you allocation overhead (and vice versa)

Overall though this is just a stylistic decision.  I find the majority of new APIs are preferring to use `Func` and `Action` over other named delegates hence I would use that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943939/whats-the-difference-between-funct-tresult-and-convertertinput-toutput?rq=1).

According to the documentation of [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), the definitions are equivalent, so I would say it's a matter of preference.

I would personally go with converter, mainly because it makes your intention clearer (not just "pass me a delegate" but "pass me a delegate that will *convert* something).

However, if all it does is convert an arbitrary object to a string, the .NET framework already provides a mechanism: it's called `.ToString` and any object should have a sensible implementation.

Comment: In what way is [`Func<T,TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) *incorrect* for its co-/contravariance?

Comment: You're right, should have checked `Func`'s documentation as well!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Although I have to admit that JaredPar makes a strong case in his answer. We seem to agree it's a matter of preference though, so choose for yourself which argument you find more convincing.

Comment: With regards to using the `.ToString()` mechanism, the class includes a default delegate that simply calls the `ToString()` method on the `T` object if a `Converter` delegate is not given. A delegate seems a nice way for a consumer of the class to specify custom formatting if the `ToString()` method for `T` doesn't produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) describes it as being used by the two `ConvertAll` methods.

> #### Remarks
>
> This delegate is used by the [`ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method of the [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) class and the [`ConvertAll<TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class to convert each element of the collection from one type to another.

I would use it only for that purpose. For any other purpose, I would use `Func`.